# SQL - How to find the person with the highest grade

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the name of the person who received the highest grade in the "Big Data" course.

I have 3 different tables:

```
People (id, name, age, address)
---------------------------------------------------
p1  | Tom Martin| 24 | 11, Integer Avenue, Fractions, MA
p2  | Al Smith  | 33 | 26, Main Street, Noman's Land, PA
p3  | Kim Burton| 40 | 45, Elm Street, Blacksburg, VA
---------------------------------------------------

Courses (cid, name, department)
---------------------------------------------------------
c1 | Systematic Torture | MATH
c2 | Pretty Painful     | CS
c3 | Not so Bad         | MATH
c4 | Big Data           | CS
---------------------------------------------------------

Grades (pid, cid, grade)
---------------------------------------------------
p1  |  c1       | 3.5 
p2  |  c3       | 2.5
p3  |  c2       | 4.0
p3  |  c4       | 3.85
---------------------------------------------------
```

I can't figure out how to find the person with the highest grade without using any fancy SQL feature. That is, I just want to use SELECT, FROM, WHERE, UNION, INTERSECT, EXCEPT, CREATE VIEW and arithmetic comparison operators like =, <, >.
My outcome is showing something other than what I try to achieve.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
    CREATE VIEW TEMPFIVE AS 
    SELECT G1.pid FROM Grades AS G1, Grades AS G2 WHERE G1.pid = G2.pid AND G1.cid = G2.cid

  SELECT People.name, Courses.name FROM TEMPFIVE, People, Courses WHERE TEMPFIVE.pid = People.pid AND Courses.name = "Big Data";

+------------+----------+
| name       | name     |
+------------+----------+
| Tom Martin | Big Data |
| Al Smith   | Big Data |
|Kim Burton  | Big Data |
|Kim Burton  | Big Data |
+------------+----------+
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? The answer may depend on it. (And don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: I am trying to find the user with the most stackoverflow homework questions, how can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, what i meant was mysql.

Comment: `without using any fancy SQL feature`, I mean, nothing fancy at all, there's no point in having artificial restrictions (I mean, I know that this is a restriction your teacher gave you, but still)

Comment: I was going to attempt an answer, but the data is so trivial that it's hard to see the edge cases, making it not worth answering IMO.

Comment: You first have to determine what the highest grade is (you could use `max`). Next you have to relate the highest grade back to the person(s) who acchieved that grade. Should be simple enough with a subquery.

Comment: What do you want if more than one person could have the highest grade?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `LIMT 1` with an `ORDER BY DESC` clause:

```
SELECT p.name, c.name, g.grade 
FROM People AS p
JOIN Grades AS g ON p.id = g.pid
JOIN Courses AS c ON c.cid = g.cid
WHERE c.name = "Big Data"
ORDER BY g.grade DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This does not cover the case when two students have the highest grade.

Comment: @SamuelRenold A way you can do that is use that query as an auxiliary table that just returns the grade. Now you just need to search for people (no limit) with that grade. (tl;dr: Nested queries)

Comment: I have posted an answer that covers the case with more students having the same maximal grade. The SQL is similar but not identical with another SQL posted by Matt.

Answer (score 0):

No Idea for MySql Query structure. So Explained in steps. I hope you can build query based on that.

1. join three tables according to their relationship
2. set course name 'Big data' in where clause
3. set grade order to DESC order
4. set the limit to fetch only first row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from(
select p.id pid,p.name name, p.age age,p.address address, 
c.cid cid, c.name coursname, c.department department,g.grade grade 
from Grades G
left join 
Courses C on g.cid = c.cid
left join
People  p on g.pid = p.id
)a where coursname= 'Big Data' order by grade desc
```

you can apply the operators on the where clause

Answer (score 0):

GiorgosBestos shoes the correct way if you only want 1 record.  If you want ties. meaning if more than 1 student has the same MAX grade then you can do a subselect as follows:

```
SELECT p.name, c.name, g.grade 
FROM
    (
       SELECT c.cid, MAX(g.grade) MaxGrade
       FROM
          Grades g
          INNER JOIN Courses c
          ON c.cid = g.cid
          AND c.name = 'Big Data'
       GROUP BY
          c.cid
    ) m
    INNER JOIN Grades g
    ON g.cid = m.cid
    AND g.grade = m.MaxGrade
    INNER JOIN People p
    ON g.pid = p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL covers the case when tow or more students have the same maximum grade:

```
SELECT P.NAME,
       C.NAME,
       G.GRADE
FROM   PEOPLE P
JOIN   GRADES G ON G.PID = P.ID
JOIN   COURSES C ON C.CID = G.CID
WHERE  C.NAME = 'Big data'
AND    G.GRADE = (SELECT MAX(G2.GRADE)
                  FROM   PEOPLE P2
                  JOIN   GRADES G2 ON G2.PID = P2.ID
                  JOIN   COURSES C2 ON C2.CID = G2.CID
                  WHERE  C2.NAME = 'Big data');
```

It is similar but not identical to the SQL proposed by Matt.