# MySQL - How to find the person with the highest grade without max, min, join, union, etc

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to solve a problem for a class and I have seen the problem asked before in the following link:[SQL - How to find the person with the highest grade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452562/sql-how-to-find-the-person-with-the-highest-grade/39452675#39452675)

I saw the answer that was provided, but noticed it can't be used to help me since it uses Joins and Order by which I'm not allowed to use, and I can't comment on the question since I am new so I'm posting the question again.

with the following 3 tables find the name of the person with the highest grade

```
People (id, name, age, address)
---------------------------------------------------
p1  | Tom Martin| 24 | 11, Wall Street, New York, NY
p2  | D.J. Tanner  | 33 | 1882, Gerard Street, San Francisco, CA
p3  | Lisa Simpson| 40 | 742, Evergreen Terrace, Springfield, IL
---------------------------------------------------

Courses (cid, name, department)
---------------------------------------------------------
c1 | Systematic Torture | MATH
c2 | Pretty Painful     | CS
c3 | Not so Bad         | MATH
c4 | Big Data           | CS
---------------------------------------------------------

Grades (pid, cid, grade)
---------------------------------------------------
p1  |  c1       | 3.5 
p2  |  c3       | 2.5
p3  |  c2       | 4.0
p3  |  c4       | 3.85
p2  |  c4       | 3.5
p1  |  c4       | 2.5
---------------------------------------------------
```

My current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT People.name
FROM Grades AS g1, Grades AS g2, people AS p1
WHERE g1.cid = 'c4'
AND g2.cid = 'c4'
AND p1.id =- g1.pid
AND g1.grade > g2.grade
```

My results:

```
Lisa Simpson
Tom Martin
```

I only need Lisa Simpson and stuck on finding a way to solve it.

The following can not be used:

```
COUNT
MAX
MIN
SUM
GROUP BY
HAVING
INNER JOIN
LEFT JOIN
RIGHT JOIN
Anything JOIN
EXISTS
NOT EXISTS
ORDER BY
TOP
```

Can only use:

```
SELECT
FROM..AS
WHERE
UNION
INTERSECT
EXCEPT
CREATE VIEW ... AS ...
Arithmetic operators like < > <= ==
AND
OR
```

Basically he won't let us use anything we didn't cover in the class

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use joins or `order by`? Your current query contains several joins. It self-joins Grades, and it joins People. It just doesn't use the explicit join syntax.

Comment: Update your question with the specific exclusions of the question.  If you can't edit your question, then provide that in a comment.  I'd like the actual question as it was posed to you.

Comment: Try ``LIMIT 1``?

Comment: Instead of "etc", can we have a definitive list of the commands we can (and/or cannot) use. For instance, there are two kinds of ORDER BY - the one that comes at the end of the query, and the one that comes inside a GROUP_CONCAT. Are we allowed to use neither? That basically leaves us with correlated subqueries, and nothing else :-(

Comment: I'm adding the methods that can not be used.

Comment: Was getting others to do your homework for you covered in class already?

Comment: And subqueries? Have you used (correlated) subqueries? It's nuts that any course would cover these before joins!

Comment: Also, you mention INTERSECT, but I'm not familiar with that construction in MySQL. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to rely on the **greater than all** operator to do it:

```
select name from people
where id = 
-- this subquery returns the id of the person with the maximum grade
(select g.pid
 from grade g
 where
 -- this is an alternative to implement the max function
 -- It means: where grade is greater then every grade that it is not itself.
 g.grade > all (select g2.grade from grade g2 where g2.grade <> g.grade)
 limit 1
)
```

This was made without joins, max and order by.

---

**Edit**: 
Explanation about the use of limit 1

The use of limit is because I am making the comparison `id = (something)`, and **that** something needs to be ONE thing of the same type as id. I cannot compare on thing of type int with a list of integers, for example. The subquery would return a list if I didn't use the limit and we had two max numbers.

Comment: What does limit do in this context?

Comment: Good explanation!

Comment: you could use `IN` though, however that could produce multiple people with highest grade, if there were multiple

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.name 
  FROM grades a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(grade) grade 
        FROM grades 
     ) b 
    ON b.grade = a.grade 
  JOIN people p 
    ON p.id = a.pid;
```

Comment: Question was, how to solve this *without* max, join, ... you used both.

Comment: @jakumi yes, it's really a ridiculous proposition

Comment: Still, that makes this very much not an answer to the question

Comment: @Strawberry I assume it's some kind of challenge, because there are often different ways to solve a problem, and using joins and order by is quite simple for anyone having basic understanding of sql. using sub-queries, like inafalcao did, is quite elegant.

Comment: @Strawberry it actually does. if the subquery could produce more than one result, it would be a set and not a scalar and thus could not be equal to some id (there could technically be more than one student with highest grade)